# How to create a single installation package of multiple drivers?

Tags: windows, installation, driver

I have downloaded multiple drivers for my Windows PC and now I want to install them all at once instead of individually. How can I create an autorun file that will install all of the drivers respectively? Or suggest other ideas if my logic is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Ninite](http://ninite.com/)

It almost has all the popular software to be installed in windows.

Comment: Thank you @iraycd. Moreover, i want to make single installation package of multiple driver softwares like wifi-driver, bluetooth-driver, LAN-driver and so on.

Comment: Please mention which OS version you are using.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64-bit OS.

Comment: It has auto installation of all the drivers. Please refer to [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driverssupport/ss/update-drivers-windows-7-tutorial.htm)